# How to convert JD to date in python?

Tags: python

How to convert JD to date, please? Here is the solution in [the opposite direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142181/calculating-julian-date-in-python).

For instance, 2416834.8134 is 20.12.1904

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743940/how-to-convert-julian-date-to-standard-date

Comment: Where is the definition of JD?  The link you gave has another link that's supposed to explain it, but it's dead.

Comment: @MohitKhandelwal unlikely, the range of numbers is completely different.

Comment: I have look at that question, but it is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert julian date to python datetime as follows:

```py
import math
from datetime import datetime
BASE_JD = 1721424.5  # Julian date of 1 January, 1
user_JD = 2416834.8134
date = datetime.fromordinal(math.floor(user_JD - BASE_JD))
# Output: datetime.datetime(1904, 12, 20, 0, 0)
```

Julian date of *1 Jan, 1* is taken from [Julian date variants - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Variants).

To print this date in any desired format, `datetime.strftime` method can be used

```py
date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
# Output: '20.12.1904'
```

Documentation-

[datetime.fromordinal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromordinal): "*Return the datetime corresponding to the proleptic Gregorian ordinal, where January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1*"

Comment: Many thanks. I obtained an error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromordinal'

Comment: I have updated the answer with fix.

Comment: Thank you very much