# convert julian days to current date and time

Tags: python, r, julian-date

I have a netCDF file. When I export it as .txt with Panoply, it transfers the date as julian dates. While downloading the data, I downloaded it every hour of every month. I tried many codes, but somehow I could not convert it to the current date correctly. Is there anyone who can help?

So I want to convert the julian date "964249" to "2010-01-01 00:00:00". My starting year 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142181/calculating-julian-date-in-python

Comment: Thank you for the return. I've tried what's written there before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 964249 is measured in hours and that the one origin is the origin stated in the question which would make the zero origin one hour before that.

```
as.POSIXct(3600 * (964249 - 1), origin = "1900-01-01", tz = "UTC")
## [1] "2010-01-01 UTC"

as.POSIXct(3600 * (964261 - 1), origin = "1900-01-01", tz = "UTC")
## [1] "2010-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"
```

### Update

Changed assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very much :) The code you suggested works up to a point, but when I change the julian date, the current date does not change. For example, when I change "964249" to "964261", the result is as follows. What do you think I'm missing?

Comment: > as.POSIXct(3600 * (964261), origin = "1900-01-01", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2010-01-01 13:00:00 UTC"

Comment: I get "2010-01-01 12:00:00 UTC" which is correct since the two are 12 hours apart.  I have added this to the answer.  Also note that I updated the answer at one point so be sure you are using the latest.

Comment: I understand your but "964249" should correspond to date 2010-01-01. I can't understand why the "964261" julia date gives the same date again. Thanks for the update too.

Comment: See my last comment.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. Yes, after reading your last comment more carefully, I understood what you mean.