# How to convert a Julian day to a datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get date and time format in python from Julian day. I have an hdf file `t1.15008.0239.mod07.hdf` and I have tried to convert Julian day `'15008'` to `datetime` like this:

```
def julday_to_masehi(julday):
    file_date= julday
    file_date = datetime.strptime(file_date, '%y%j')
    file_date = file_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return file_date

julday = '15232'
datetimee = julday_to_masehi(julday)
print(datetimee)
```

and the result is `2015-08-20`.

But I also need the time. If I try `julday = '150080239'` and change
the to code to: `file_date = file_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`, then
I get an error.

So how can I convert Julian day `'150080239'` into python
`datetime` in format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`?

Comment: You might want to peruse the Python datetime documentation.  It's currently at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html.  There are a lot of good manipulation methods there.

Comment: ["julian day" may mean different things in different cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25831416/4279). What result do you expect for `00232` and `100232` ?

Comment: [read the description of `%H`, `%M` time formats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

```
date, time = jul_date_time.split('.')
hour = int(time[:2])
minute = int(time[2:])
```

You already showed you can handle the date; this lets you construct a Python time -- and datetime -- from the pieces of the input string.

Is that what you need?

Comment: no, the time '0239' is julian day. oh i;m sorry i forget to show the piece of the code. i just send part of the date like this julday = '15232' and send it to funtion like this:datetimee = julday_to_masehi(julday). Of course it just return the date like '20150820'.i think  it's need to change the code of function file_date = datetime.strptime(file_date, '%y%j'), but i don't know how?

Comment: Please add the missing code to your question; it's hard to read in this format.  Also, please describe how you know the time of day.  I thought that "15008" is supposed to be 2015, 08 Jan (8th day of the year).  You'll have to describe your inputs in detail if you want a proper solution.