# How to convert Julian date to standard date?

Tags: python, string, date, python-3.x

I have a string as Julian date like `"16152"` meaning 152'nd day of 2016 or `"15234"` meaning 234'th day of 2015.

How can I convert these Julian dates to format like `20/05/2016` using Python 3 standard library?

I can get the year 2016 like this: `date = 20 + julian[0:1]`, where `julian` is the string containing the Julian date, but how can I calculate the rest according to 1th of January?

Comment: Unrelated, but [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) is a different animal : *Julian day is the continuous count of days since the beginning of the Julian Period used primarily by astronomers*

Comment: the reverse operation: [Extract day of year and Julian day from a string date in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25831416/4279)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method supports the *day of year* format:

```
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('16234', '%y%j').date()
datetime.date(2016, 8, 21)
```

And then you can use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to reformat the date

```
>>> date = datetime.date(2016, 8, 21)
>>> date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'21/08/2016'
```

Comment: is it possible to do this with fractions of day to get time as well?

Answer (score 4):

Well, first, create a `datetime` object (from the module `datetime`)

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
julian = ... # Your julian datetime
date = datetime.strptime("1/1/" + jul[:2], "%m/%d/%y") 
# Just initializing the start date, which will be January 1st in the year of the Julian date (2 first chars)
```

Now add the days from the start date:

```
daysToAdd = int(julian[2:]) # Taking the days and converting to int
date += timedelta(days = daysToAdd - 1)
```

Now, you can just print it as is:

```
print(str(date))
```

Or you can use `strftime()` function.

```
print(date.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```

Read more about `strftime` format string [here](http://strftime.org/)

Comment: It is unneccessary to call the `str` function on an object if you're printing it. The `print` function will call the `__str__` method itself. Just this: `print(datetime.now())`, for example, is sufficient

Answer (score -1):

Easy way

- Convert from regular date to Julian date

`print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%j")`

- Convert from Julian date to regular date

`print datetime.datetime.strptime('19155', '%y%j').strftime("%d-%m-%Y")`

Answer (score -1):

I used this for changing a Juian date to xml xsd:datetime

```py
def julianDate2ISO8601(d, offset='+00:00'):
    """
     return ISO8601 formated datetime from julian date
     optional offset  [+|-]hh:mm
    """
    d = str(d)  # make sure it is a string
    # replace leading number with correct century
    centuryArray = ['19','20','21']
    d = centuryArray[int(d[:1])] + d[1:]
    # format string to iso 8601 datetime
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%j').date().strftime(
        '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00') + offset
```