# converting form Julian date to gregorian date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Julian date: 736257, I need help converting it from Julian date to Gregorian date in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 convert Julian date to standard date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743940/python3-convert-julian-date-to-standard-date)

Comment: @ndmeiri This appears to be the "days since 1AD" meaning of Julian date rather than the "year * 1000 + days since the start of this year" meaning, so that question and its answers won't help.

Comment: Just to be clear, the number you've chosen translates to Friday, Oct  6, 2698 B.C.  Does that match your expectation?

Comment: @Robᵩ I suspect he means 21 Oct 2016. Astronomers aren't the only ones who use JDNs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "Julian date" has two different meanings, and different variations for each.

I think you're looking for the "days since epoch" meaning, and using the 1 Jan 1 CE epoch rather than the more common astronomers' epoch of 4713 BCE or [any of the other alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Variants). You can adjust that pretty easily.

```
>>> datetime.date(1, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=736257)
datetime.date(2016, 10, 21)
```

That's all there is to it. (Which is the point of using Julian dates in the first place.)

---

Notice that under the covers, [this is the same format Python `datetime` is already using](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/datetime.py#L82), for its [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) and `datetime` types, except that Python uses midnight UTC instead of local noon. If that's what you want, it's even easier:

```
>>> datetime.date.fromordinal(736257)
datetime.date(2016, 10, 20, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks abarnert, how to i convert the gregorian date back to Julian date?

Comment: All the options are in the docs I linked. You can use `toordinal` to get the Python definition, you can subtract `date(1,1,1)` to get a `timedelta` and pull the days out of that to get the other definition, etc.

Comment: Thanks, i use the toordinal .                                                       >>>from datetime import datetime                                                      >>> datetime.strptime("2016-10-20", "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()