# Non-standard Julian day time stamp

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

I have a timestamp in a non-standard format, its a concatenation of a number of elements. I'd like to convert at least the last part of the string into hours/minutes/seconds/decimal seconds so I can calculate the time gap between them (typically of the order of 2-5 seconds).
I have looked at this link but it assumes a 'proper' Julian time. [How to convert Julian date to standard date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743940/how-to-convert-julian-date-to-standard-date)

My time stamp looks like this

> 1380643373

It is set up as ddd hh mm ss.s
This timestamp represent 138th day, 06:43:37.3

Is there a datetime method of working with this or do I need to strip out the various parts (hh,mm,ss.s) and concatenate them in some way? As I am only interested in the seconds, if I can just extract them I could deal with that by adding 60 if the second timestamp is smaller than the first - i.e event passes over the minute change boundary.

Comment: Is the timestamp an integer or string?

Comment: It is part of a text file, so presumably by default, a string, but I would either extract it to a dataframe or if easier, do the maths on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in seconds, you can do:

```
timestamp = 1380643373
seconds = (timestamp % 1000) / 10 # Gives 37.3
```

`timestamp % 1000` gives you the last three digits of `timestamp`. Then you divide that by 10 to get seconds.

If it's a string, you can take the last three characters by slicing it.

```
timestamp = "1380643373"
seconds = int(timestamp[-3:]) / 10 # Gives 37.3
```

It's pretty easy to convert the timestamp to a datetime using the `divmod()` function repeatedly:

```
import datetime

base_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) # Midnight on Jan 1 2000


timestamp = 1380643373

timestamp, seconds = divmod(timestamp, 1000) # Gives 1380643, 373
seconds = seconds / 10 # Gives 37.3

timestamp, minutes = divmod(timestamp, 100) # Gives 13806, 43

days, hours = divmod(timestamp, 100) # Gives 138, 6


tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=days, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds) # Gives datetime.timedelta(days=138, seconds=24217, microseconds=300000)
new_date = base_date + tdelta
```