# Extract Month From Julian day and year in python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have essentially the opposite question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943062/extract-day-of-year-and-julian-day-from-a-string-date-in-python). I have a string structured as `"%y%j"` such that January 1 2017 would be `"17001"` and December 31 1995 would be `"95365"`.

I essentially need to know what month it is from any given input string. I thought this would be relatively simple. Something like:

```
input = "95365"
year = int(input[0:2])
day = int(input[2:5])
if day < 32:
    month = 1
if day >= 32 and day < 50:
    # etc...
```

what I failed to remember was leap years and how often they repeat. Does anyone have an easy fix? Is there a library for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, I think all you need is:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = '95365'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%y%j').month
12
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%y%j').day
31
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%y%j').year
1995
```

Comment: I think this is exactly correct. Much cleaner than a thousand "if" statements.