# Splitting a CSV column into two

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

Column 2 within my csv file looks like the following:

```
20150926T104044Z
20150926T104131Z
```

and so on.

I have a definition created that will change the listed date into a julian date, but was wondering how I can go about altering this specific column of data?

Is there a way I can make python change the dates within the csv to a their julian date equivalent? Can I split the column into two csv's and translate the julian date from there?

Comment: Are you wanting it split down the middle?  For example, the first line turned into `20150926` and `T104044Z`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be overthinking it.  Try this.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import csv

def get_julian(_date):
    # _date is holding 20150926T104044Z
    the_date = parse(_date)
    julian_start = parse('19000101T000000Z')
    julian_days = (the_date - julian_start).days
    return julian_days

with open('filename.csv') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # Column 2, right?
        row[1] = get_julian(row[1])

        # Do things and stuff with your corrected data.
```

Comment: `dateutil` isn't in the stdlib though

Comment: That was not a stated requirement.

Comment: I could have and it's ABSOLUTELY the better way to do it, but the suggested code change wasn't CSV specific, so I left that up to @OP to insert.

Comment: Truthfully, I just didn't want to go look up the CSV syntax.

Comment: Why not just show the right way the first time? If OP hits a line like this, `one,"two,three,four",five`, your code breaks... column 2 right?

Comment: It was the right way for the data in question since he gave us a sample of the data.  However, csv is implemented.

Comment: Your edit seems to have broken your answer? Can you show your tests?

Comment: Fixed.  Just a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that there are many interpretations to [Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), One is Oridinal date(day of the year) and another one day from Monday, January 1, 4713 BC.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import jdcal

df = pd.read_csv("path/to/your/csv")


def tojulianDate(date):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ').strftime('%y%j')
def tojulianDate2(date):
    curr_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    curr_date_tuple = curr_date.timetuple()
    return int(sum(jdcal.gcal2jd(curr_date_tuple.tm_year, curr_date_tuple.tm_mon, curr_date_tuple.tm_mday)))
df['Calendar_Dates'] = df['Calendar_Dates'].apply(tojulianDate2)

df.to_csv('path/to/modified/csv')
```

Method "toJulianDate" can be used to get the day of the year or Oridinal Date.
for second format, there is a library called [jdcal](https://pypi.org/project/jdcal/1.0/#description) to convert gregorian date to julian day or vice versa which is done in toJulianDate2 . This can also be done directly by opening csv and without loading into a dataframe.

Similar question was answered here [Extract day of year and Julian day from a string date in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943062/extract-day-of-year-and-julian-day-from-a-string-date-in-python/25831416#25831416)